# Find the max in specific dim and replace by 1 and other 0 in pytorch

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch

I have the following tensors:

```
index = tensor([[1, 1, 1, …, 0, 0, 1],
[0, 0, 2, …, 1, 1, 1],
[1, 1, 0, …, 0, 1, 0],
…,
[0, 1, 2, …, 0, 2, 1],
[2, 0, 1, …, 0, 1, 0],
[2, 1, 1, …, 1, 1, 1]])

index.size() = torch.Size([20, 3001])
```

Also, I have the source tensor which is:

```
source = torch.zeros(20, 3, 3001)
source.size() = torch.Size([20, 3, 3001])
```

I would like to use the index tensor and replace the 1 with the source tensor in dim=1.
I know I should use scatter, but I could not able to replace it.
Could you please help me?
Thanks

Comment: Can you show example output that you want to achieve?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply a [`torch.Tensor.scatter`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.Tensor.scatter_.html#torch.Tensor.scatter_) operator on `source`, the only constraint is for `source` and `index` to have the same number of dimensions. The desired operation here is:

```
source[i][index[i][:][k]][k] = 1
```

Which is achieved by unsqueezing a dimension on `index` at `dim=1` and applying `scatter`:

```
>>> source.scatter(dim=1, index=index[:,None], value=1)
```